# About Dataset：HYCOM Water Temperature and Salinity

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I am using the dataset HYCOM Water Temperature and Salinity for my work. However, I find its image ID a bit confusing. For example, for the ImageCollection filtered by Date of '2019-01-01' to '2019-01-02', there are 8 images for one specific day which seems to have no difference:

> HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity/2019010100
>
> HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity/2019010103
>
> ...
>
> HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity/2019010121

I am wondering if there is anyone who knows the temporal resolution of this dataset and the rule of image ID naming.